How to get a property from parent
I have this pom.xml, where spring.boot.version property is defined in the parent pom.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.seurop.eca.ocb.middyweb.mackoffice.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>ocb-kw-mackoffice-server</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>ocb-kw-mackoffice-server-annotations</artifactId>
    <name>ocb-kw-mackoffice-server-annotations</name>

    <!-- Properties Section -->
    <properties>
        <parent.version>6.0.0</parent.version>
        <eclipselink.version>2.7.12</eclipselink.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
...

</project>

Nevertheless, I have this error

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:${spring.boot.version} was not found in...

Here is the parent pom with all dependencies:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.seurop.eca.ocb.middyweb.mackoffice.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>ocb-kw-mackoffice-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <name>huti</name>
  
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>2.7.18</spring-boot.version>
        <activiti.version>6.0.0</activiti.version>
        <commons-csv.version>1.12.0</commons-csv.version>
        <eclipselink.version>4.0.4</eclipselink.version>
        <h2.version>2.1.210</h2.version>
        <jackson.version>2.16.1</jackson.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <javax.mail.version>1.4.7</javax.mail.version>
        <jasperreports-functions.version>6.19.1</jasperreports-functions.version>
        <jasperreports.version>6.19.1</jasperreports.version>
        <junit-jupiter-engine.version>5.2.0</junit-jupiter-engine.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.34</lombok.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.21.0</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <oracle.version>11.2.0.4</oracle.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-test-dbunit.version>1.3.0</spring-test-dbunit.version>
        <springfox.version>2.9.2</springfox.version>
        <tomcat-embed-core.version>9.0.56</tomcat-embed-core.version>
    </properties>

....
</project>


is this the full dependency for springboot ?

Voting to close as a typo. The parent POM defines the property spring-boot.version, not spring.boot.version.

As an aside, if you use Spring Boot and its dependency management properly, there is no reason to specify versions for Spring Boot starters provided by the Spring Boot project, as those versions would already be managed by Spring Boot itself.

I would use <dependencyManagement> instead of version properties.
In the parent pom only some local properties that are repeated:
<properties>
    <spring-boot.version>2.7.18</spring-boot.version>
    <jackson.version>2.16.1</jackson.version>
    <junit-jupiter-engine.version>5.2.0</junit-jupiter-engine.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.34</lombok.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>

And in the using modules you need no versions.
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Agreed, intuitively peoply like such nice looking lists of named properties,
but bare bone dependencyManagement makes sense (and will be more consistent). Ctrl-Space in <version> will list available versions and such.
